# Need help about PHP modules on RHEL 7.2- Apache shows code instead of executing it

Tags: rhel, apache-httpd, php7

On my rhel 7.2 system, I finished installing Apache 2.4.46 and PHP 7.4.19. However, when I start apache and access to my own php file, it shows source code instead of executing it.
I find some solution on the Internet and try some changes in httpd.conf file such as adding this:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

and

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

unfortunately, it doesn't work.
I realized that it does not have file "php.conf" in folder  /etc/httpd/conf.d or file libphp7 in any folder.

So, how can I address this problem. Hope you guys would help me.
Thank in advanced!!!

Comment: Did you enable the PHP module and restart apache afterwards? Is there an error in the logs?

Comment: After checking my php module in apache, I found out that there were any module file in apache. Thanks a lot, bro!